# is there any way to pass variables to node.js from browser without form or without input tag?

Tags: node.js, routes

i am writing a node.js code. in browser side I have gotten all the file names from server. Now I want to open one of these files by clicking on it?
How can I pass the name of the file to the server without using a form?
actually I use form, but I don't have an input. therefore I can not recognize the datas in node.js?
I have for example 10

tag and for every tag a file name . by clicking on this name, I must send the name of the file to server. 
here is my client side code:

```
   <form  action="openMEasText" method="POST">
     <ul>
       <%articles.forEach(file => {%>
       <li ><input type="submit" method="POST" name= 
       <%=file.slice(0,-4);%>/></li>
       <%  });%>

     </ul>
   </form>
```

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a form.
You can send a HTTP post request from front-end with libraries like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).
use `onclick` event and send the name of file to back-end.

```
<li onclick="makePostRequest("fileName")"><%=fileName %></li>
<script>
    function makePostRequest(name) {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/route-you-define-in-backend',
            data: {
                fileName: name,
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

In back-end handle the post request the way you want

```
app.post('/route-you-define-in-backend',
(req, res)=> {
    // req.body.fileName
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I have installed axios. but it says that axios is not defined. what should I do that my js code understand it?
thanks  a lot

Comment: if my answer was useful select it as correct answer then submit new question and post your code so i can find the problem.